# C.Binary Insertion sort

Tags: c, insert, insertion-sort

Please tell me what the error is.The program returns a huge value, instead of 0, and creates an empty excel file.

(If anything, then the essence of the program is that,use Binary Insertion sort  on different numbers of elements and output the average value of swaps and comps)

I would be very grateful for the edits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int binarySearch(int* arr,int elem, int start, int end, int* comps)
{
    (*comps)++;
    if (end <= start)
    {
        (*comps) ++;
        return (elem > arr[start])? (start + 1): start;
    } 
    
    int mid = (start + end)/2;
    (*comps)++;
    if(elem == arr[mid]) return mid+1;
    (*comps)++;
    if(elem > arr[mid]) return binarySearch(arr, elem, mid+1, end, comps);
    return binarySearch(arr, elem, start, mid-1, comps);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE *f=fopen("stat8.csv","w");
    int n=100;
    int i,s;
    while (n<=10000){
    int st=0;
    for (s=0;s<5;s++)
    {
        int *a;
        a=(int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
        srand(time(NULL));
        int k;
        for (k=0;k<n;k++)
        {
            *(a+i)=rand()%50;
        }
        int j,comps,swaps;
        swaps=0;
        comps=0;
for( i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        int j = i - 1;
        int selected = a[i];
        int loc = binarySearch(a,selected,0,j,comps);
        while(j >= loc)
        {
            comps++;
            swaps++;
            a[j+1] = a[j];
            j--;
        }
        a[j+1] = selected;
        comps++;
    }
    st+=swaps + comps;  
}
        
    st=st/5;
    fprintf(f,"%d ; %d\n", n , st);
    if (n<1000){
        n+=100;}
    else {n+=1000;} 
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but `srand` should be called *once* , not in a loop. Also please fix your indentation and inconsistent block formatting, it is not readable.

Comment: I used srand in a loop in the basic insertion sort and everything was fine.

Comment: I gave you a suggestion on how it needs to be in order to be correct. Take it or leave it.

Comment: Here: `int loc = binarySearch(a,selected,0,j,comps);` you pass in the integer `comps`, but the function requires a pointer to an int. Pass the address `&comps`.

Comment: @MOehm Oh, really.Thanks a lot.I hope everything else is correct, and everything counts correctly too...